# Distinct values with geoQuery works in Mongo but not in Spring

Tags: spring, mongodb, geolocation, distinct

While this works in mongo:

```
> db.collection.distinct( "key", {"position":{$geoWithin:{$box: [[-6.8, 36.7], [-0.5, 43.8]]}}} )
> [ "A", "B" ]
```

In spring returns an error

```
Criteria criteria = Criteria.where("position").within(box);
        Query query = new Query();
        query.addCriteria(criteria);
 List<String> result = mongoOperations.getCollection("collection")
                .distinct("key", query.getQueryObject());
```

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: can't serialize class org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.GeoCommand
    at org.bson.BasicBSONEncoder._putObjectField(BasicBSONEncoder.java:299) ~[mongo-java-driver-2.14.3.jar:na]
    at org.bson.BasicBSONEncoder.putObject(BasicBSONEncoder.java:194) ~[mongo-java-driver-2.14.3.jar:na]
    at org.bson.BasicBSONEncoder._putObjectField(BasicBSONEncoder.java:255) ~[mongo-java-driver-2.14.3.jar:na]
    at org.bson.BasicBSONEncoder.putObject(BasicBSONEncoder.java:194) ~[mongo-java-driver-2.14.3.jar:na]
    at org.bson.BasicBSONEncoder._putObjectField(BasicBSONEncoder.java:255) ~[mongo-java-driver-2.14.3.jar:na]
    at org.bson.BasicBSONEncoder.putObject(BasicBSONEncoder.java:194) ~[mongo-java-driver-2.14.3.jar:na]
    at org.bson.BasicBSONEncoder.putObject(BasicBSONEncoder.java:136) ~[mongo-java-driver-2.14.3.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.DefaultDBEncoder.writeObject(DefaultDBEncoder.java:36) ~[mongo-java-driver-2.14.3.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.OutMessage.putObject(OutMessage.java:289) ~[mongo-java-driver-2.14.3.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.OutMessage.writeQuery(OutMessage.java:211) ~[mongo-java-driver-2.14.3.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.OutMessage.query(OutMessage.java:86) ~[mongo-java-driver-2.14.3.jar:na]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't able to make @Christoph Strobl code to even compile!

I finally used mongo-java-driver to get the distinct values:

```
    MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient();
    MongoDatabase database = mongoClient.getDatabase(dbName);
    MongoCollection<org.bson.Document> collection = database.getCollection(COLLECTION);
    Bson query = Filters.geoWithinBox("position", 
            x1, y1, x2, y2);

    DistinctIterable<String> resultList = collection.distinct("key", query, String.class);

    Set resultSet = new HashSet();
    resultList.forEach(new Block<String>() {
        @Override
        public void apply(final String result) {
            resultSet.add(result);
        }
    });

    return resultSet;
```

Answer (score 0):

I do see the need to go through the MongoDB Java driver API directly using the operations of the *collection*. However `Query.getQueryObject()` cannot be directly used with the underlying driver as it gets transformed by the `QueryMapper`.
For now, you can try to do the mapping on your own.

```java
QueryMapper mapper = new QueryMapper(mongoOperations.getConverter());
org.bson.Document mappedQuery = mapper.getMappedObject(query.getQueryObject(), Optional.empty());

List<String> result = template.getCollection("collection")
    .distinct("key", mappedQuery, String.class)
    .into(new ArrayList<>());
```

There's also [DATAMONGO-1761](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAMONGO-1761) (tough still open) seeking to add support for `distinct` to `MongoOperations`.